# How do I activate a different logging level for Thymeleaf?

Tags: spring-boot, logging, thymeleaf

The application I'm working with decided to not render one template and I can't figure why. Request mapping, file references and all seem correct.

The default logging level is set to INFO and I tried to set to TRACE using these entries on `application.properties`:

```
logging.level.org.thymeleaf=TRACE
logging.level.<namespace-to-controllers>=TRACE
```

Still, it does not seems to provide any extra information.

Please advise!

Comment: Are you providing your own `logback.xml`?

Comment: Nope, using stock spring boot settings.

Comment: You can try enabling TRACE for the ROOT logger.

Comment: By setting this, I get all the TRACE output for all the application - which is way too much detail for me to filter out, but it's a start.

Comment: So basically setting the level works. You can try adding `org.springframework.web` and enable TRACE (or DEBUG) for that instead of everything. Not sure if `org.thymeleaf` is producing much additional output.